# Moving from Eclipse to Vim for my pet Python

Tags: python, eclipse, vim, plugins

I am a programer going through a early-mid coder crisis. I was brought up on Elipse, learning it as I learned java. and when I had to learn C I ran back to it, because its code completion, debugger and understandable interface were like an old security blanket when the school wanted us to use a horribly slow and unforgiving watered down form of emacs. But now my old second hand ford torus of an IDE is showing its faults. It's slow with almost everything, and its code completion is not so great with python. So I think its time to put the ol' girl in the shed and pick out a new sleek and fast Miata to take on the code. 
I hear Vim is nice, and it comes in a convertible which is always great. But I am quite dim, and afraid of new things so other than the given tutorial from the vim site, are there any good tutorials with a mind for python, my eyes are going so pictures are nice. Also I hear that Vim is great because of all of its plug-ins. So what are some of the good ones for python, like with eclipse I would like smart code completion, smart error checking (red squiggles like eclipse), and a debugger while not a must but a nice to have, and maybe something in red with racing stripes.
Also, I don't consider using the mouse as a bad thing, or maybe just not yet, so any plug-ins or tips for that would be nice too.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python?rq=1

Comment: I prefer Komodo Edit/IDE because of the language support, code completion, and plugins. I've never been much of a fan of VIM when it comes to development, but it's definitely great for a quick remote code edit

Comment: +1 just for the wording

Comment: @anakata that's a great find, I wish it included general running speeds of each one, but that might be a little much. While I will look into some of those, I would like to try and stick with Vim because, I'm assuming, it will just be easier to transfer to a different language in Vim then some of the others.

Comment: There are tons of vim+python tutorials/articles on the web. Did you read them?

Comment: @romani some of them and I'm still looking, but I was hopping that I could get the help of others who have been there before and had already sifted through the web for the best sites

Comment: Ignore the plugins for now.  Learn the core editor first.  Learn it well.